# Azure API Management and Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I am searching for a solution to expose an `Azure SQL DB` table over the `Azure API Management` and then allow a `Kubernetes` hosted app to talk with the `Azure SQL DB` over this `API`. What would be the less time consuming approach for building this `API` to expose the table?
I have found doc for couple of solution, but coming from the BigData world, I couldn't figure it out which is worth to invest the time and to build it. Any suggestion where should I take a closer look?

For example this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6SlmoXWf3o

Answer (score 0):

What is the configuration of your Azure SQL server. By default the networking configuration of the server is always "Allow all".

[image: Firewalls and virtual networks]

This setting can be found at Firewalls and virtual networks.

When Deny public network access is set to Yes, only connections via private endpoints are allowed. When this setting is No (default), customers can connect by using either public endpoints (with IP-based firewall rules or with virtual-network-based firewall rules) or private endpoints (by using Azure Private Link)

Comment: Hi,this is not the problem. I am searching for a feasible way to create the API. Like which API can I used? OpenAPI? Build one by myself in .NetCore. There is no dedicate API for Azure SQL in Azure, from what I have seeing. Any idea?

Comment: Okay, got it. For this, as far as I understand, you can create an application that will run on kubernetes pod. A .NetCore like you mentioned, or a JAVA Springboot Rest API etc. But you need to have some application running on a pod and build an API on your own to be able to access the MSSQL.

Comment: I have thought about a serverless solution. An Azure function maybe, with .NetCore?